# "Dass" benutze ich zu viel

Tags: conjunction

Donnerstag habe ich mein B2 Goethe Examen. Ich habe schreiben viel geübt und meine Lehrerin sagt, dass ich zu viel ', dass...' benutze. Ich weiß nicht, wie ich es sagen soll, aber ich versuche es: was kann ich schreiben anstatt ', dass...'? Ich hoffe, jemand kann mir bald helfen! Ich weiß, es ist nicht falsch , 'dass' zu nutzen, aber ich möchte mein Examen schaffen!

Beispielsätze:

> Doch möchte ich Ihnen vorschlagen, dass ich nur am Wochenende arbeite.
>
> Mir ist klar, dass es schwierig für Sie ist.
>
> Ein wesentlicher Grund dafür ist, dass man mehr weiß über Tierleid.
>
> Was dagegen spricht, nie mehr Fastfood zu essen, ist, dass man auch Kilos verlieren kann.

Comment: Hast du ein paar Beispielsätze für uns?

Comment: Bis Donnerstag ist keine Zeit, um noch viel zu verändern. Deshalb keine Experimente!

Comment: Es ist ein Unterschied zwischen "zu viel *dass* nutzen" und "*dass* falsch nutzen". Offensichtlich wird *dass* richtig benutzt, das ist das wichtigste! Daher: Toitoitoi zum Examen und danach bitte mit Beispielsätzen die Frage anreichern.

Comment: "Zu viel *dass* nutzen" ist eine Frage des Stils. Daran sollte das Examen nicht scheitern. Was du schreibst, sieht in meinen Augen sehr gut aus. Also keine Sorge! Am Stil kann man später noch arbeiten.

Comment: Der letzte Satz sagt, glaube ich, nicht was er soll. Kilos verlieren ist doch für die meisten erwünscht! "Gegen Fastfood essen spricht, dass es Übergewicht verursacht." Der Ausdruck "dass man auch Kilo verlieren kann" wird zwar verstanden, klingt arg umgangssprachlich. "... dass man auch Gewicht verlieren kann" wäre besser, egal ob man das begrüßt oder befürchtet.

Comment: @userunknown: Während ich zustimme, dass der Satz arg holprig ist und aufgrund "Sprachschule" die Zielaussage wohl dem entspricht, was die Mehrheit anstrebt - bin ich der Meinung, dass es trotzdem als Nachteil angesehen werden kann. Und sei es nur, weil ich z.B. Krebspatient bin und mangels Appetit jede einzelne gegessene Kalorie Gold wert ist.

Comment: Ich hoffe, jemand kann mir bald helfen! - Hier hast du "dass" nicht benutzt ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Da du dass korrekt verwendest, denke ich, dass es nicht unbedingt nötig ist, dass du es in so kurzer Zeit änderst.

---

Aber grundsätzlich sehe ich drei Möglichkeiten, um dass zu umgehen:

1. Infinitivsätze:

> Was gegen Fastfood essen spricht, ist, Kilos verlieren zu können.
>
> Doch möchte ich Ihnen vorschlagen, nur am Wochenende zu arbeiten.

(Achtung: Die Bedeutung hat sich hier leicht geändert, das **Gegenüber** soll nun am Wochenende arbeiten, da Infinitivsätze keine Informationen über das Subjekt enthalten)

---

2. Andere Formulierungen & Konjunktionen wählen:

> Mir ist klar, wie schwierig es für Sie ist.

-> Pronominalsatz

> Man weiß [inzwischen] mehr über Tierleid, was ein wesentlicher Grund für ___ ist.

-> Pronominalsatz / Relativsatz

> Meine Deutschlehrerin sagt mir, ich benutzte dass zu oft.

-> Konjunktiv & uneingeleiteter Nebensatz

> Vielen Dank, dass du mir geholfen hast.
> ->
> Vielen Dank für deine Hilfe.

---

3. Oft kann es ohne Änderung, nur durch verschieben des Verbs weggelassen werden:

> Ich hoffe, dass du mich bald besuchst.

wird zu

> Ich hoffe, du besuchst mich bald.

---

Diese Taktiken können wir auch auf den ersten Satz dieser Antwort anwenden:

> Da du dass korrekt verwendest, denke ich, es ist nicht unbedingt nötig, es in so kurzer Zeit zu ändern.

-> Das erste dass konnte man hier ohne Probleme weglassen, nur die Stellung des Verbs (ist) hat sich geändert.

-> Das zweite dass konnte hier mit einem Infinitivsatz umgangen werden.

Comment: Wow, wie viele Möglichkeiten es doch gibt. Und guter Hinweis mit der Bedeutungsänderung beim Infinitiv. (+1)

Comment: "Wenn man auf Fastfood verzichtet verliert man auch Kilos." Ich vermute gemeint ist, dass Kilos zu verlieren erwünscht ist, deswegen spricht dass nicht gegen den Verzicht, sondern für ihn - aber das ist natürlich Semantik und war in der Frage schon so schief angelegt. "Fastfood kann Übergewicht verursachen."

Comment: Ich finde eine Bedeutungsänderung - und die im Beispielsatz ist nicht gerade klein - ist somit kein Beispiel für einen Umbau ohne dass. Geht die gleiche Bedeutung nur im dass-Konstrukt, dann gibt es keinen Umbau. Die restlichen Beispiele finde ich top.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm, stimmt schon. Allerdings ist es im besagten Fall, wenn man es genau nimmt, kein Ändern, sondern ein Uneindeutigmachen. Es hängt nun vom Kontext ab, wer laut Vorschlag am Wochenende arbeiten soll. Aber streng genommen haben Sie recht, weil die Eindeutigkeit des Dass-Satzes beim Umbau verlorengegangen.

Answer (score 0):

Man kann den Konjunktiv benutzen. Statt

> Ich sagte, dass du zuviel "dass" benutzt.

kann man schreiben

> Ich sagte du schriebest zuviel "dass".

Man kann es aber auch komplett umschreiben:

Ich beklagte deinen übermässigen Gebrauch von "dass".

Comment: Zwar haben Sie recht damit, dass man (häufig, aber nicht immer) den Konjunktiv benutzen kann, allerdings nicht den von Ihnen verwendeten Irrealis *schriebest*. Der Nebensatz – vor dem übrigens noch ein Komma gehört – soll ja hier nur innerlich abhängig vom Hauptsatz gemacht werden, und dazu benutzt man den Obliquus, hier also *schreibest*. Ein anderes Problem habe ich mit der Auswahl Ihres Beispielsatzes. Der eignet sich nicht besonders gut, weil die beiden vorgeschlagenen Umschreibungen sehr gestelzt klingen.

Answer (score 0):

> Doch möchte ich Ihnen vorschlagen, dass ich nur am Wochenende arbeite.

"Ich schlage Ihnen vor nur am Wochenende zu arbeiten." but your sentence is better, because the second could also mean that the other (not the speaker) should work at Weekends.  You can also use this  "Mein Vorschlag: ich arbeite nur am Wochenende.". But also in this case your first sentence with "dass" is better, because the second sounds like you say it to your coleague and not to your boss.